# Issue i am getting during LockMode.READ in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

**As per LockMode.READ:-**  Objects in this lock mode were read from the database in the current transaction, rather than being pulled from a cache.

So I tried below code snippet

```
Session session = sessions.openSession();
tx = session.beginTransaction();
person = (Person)session. get(Person.class,1);//Line1
session.lock(person, LockMode.READ);//Line2
person = (Person)session. get(Person.class,1);//Line3
```

At line 1 database query got fired as I am getting person first time in session.

**As per definition of `LockMode.READ` above I was expecting the database query to fire at line 3 too. But it did not - why?**

Just for information query which got fired at line 1 is

```
Select person0_.id as id0_1_, person0_.cname as cname0_1_, 
person0_.addressId1 as addressId3_0_1_, address1_.id as id1_0_, address1_.personId 
as personId1_0_, address1_.addressLine1 as addressL3_1_0_ from MyProject1.Person 
person0_, MyProject1.Address address1_ where person0_.addressId1=address1_.id(+) 
and person0_.id=?
```

**EDIT**

```
Session session = sessions.openSession();
tx = session.beginTransaction();
person = (Person)session. get(Person.class,1);
tx.commit();
session.close();



Session session = sessions.openSession();
tx = session.beginTransaction();
person = (Person)session. get(Person.class,1);//Line1
session.lock(person, LockMode.READ);//Line2
person = (Person)session. get(Person.class,1);//Line3
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Now at line 2 i see one more query got fired **which is  select id from MyProject1.Person where id =?** but  it does not fire the query for person for id 1 and does not get updated person value  neither at line 2 an line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to not to read it from the database again. Behavior is consistent with Javadoc. In your code Line1 and Line3 are in same transaction, so **"in the current transaction"** still holds.

Comment: Hi mikko . See my edited post.Still LockMode.read does not get the value from database even if i am getting in another transaction